# Subset of rows of an unitary matrix is a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

This is taken from exercise 4.1.8 in High-Dimensional Probability by Roman Vershynin.

Question:

Let $U$ be unitary and let $R$ be a sub-matrix of $U$ obtained by selecting a subset of its rows. Show that $R$ is a projection.

My thoughts:

Since $U$ is unitary it is square, say $n \times n$. We take away $n-m > 0$ rows from $U$ to form $R$ which is then $m \times n$. Now $R$ can't be a projection since it isn't square (and thus can't satisfy $R^{2} = R$). I suppose I have misinterpreted something?

Comment: See remark 4.1.7 which describes rectangular projection matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remark that CyclotomicField points to in the comment states that if $R^{T} R$ is an orthogonal projection, then we say that $R$ is a projection.